# Ember's link-to helper not linking to correct URL when using {{#each x in model}} syntax?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a router that looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("manage", function() {
        this.resource('services' , function() {
            this.route("new");
            this.route("edit", { path: '/edit/:service_id' } );
        });
    });
});
```

The services.index route loads the model from the server:

```
App.ServicesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {  
        return this.store.find('service');
    }
});
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "services" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "serviceId" : "service1",
    "name" : "Service A"
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "serviceId" : "service2",
    "name" : "Service B"
  } ]
}
```

Then inside the `services` index template I'm listing the services returned by the server with a `{{each}}` loop, like so:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each service in model}}
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>{{service.serviceId}}</td>
            <td>{{service.name}}</td>
            <td>{{#link-to 'services.edit' this}}Edit{{/link-to}} - <a href="#" {{action 'deleteService' this}}>Delete</a></td>
        </tr><!-- Table Row -->
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

The issue is that when the template renders, it replaces the path segment with "undefined":

```
<a id="ember502" class="ember-view" href="#/manage/services/edit/undefined">Edit</a>
```

...and the `deleteService` method gets passed an object which has a property with two services, instead of the service instance in question.

Then I tried:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each}}
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>{{serviceId}}</td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{#link-to 'services.edit' this}}Edit{{/link-to}} - <a href="#" {{action 'deleteService' this}}>Delete</a></td>
        </tr><!-- Table Row -->
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

**and it worked!**

I'm trying to understand what happened in the previous attempt. I'm trying to use the {{@each x in model}} syntax and would like to understand why the `this` didn't work with that setup...

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `this` to `service` or whatever you named the iterated items, it should work.

```
{{#link-to 'services.edit' service}}Edit{{/link-to}}
```

Just like JS, if you override `this` with some particular context (think `call, apply, bind, etc.`) you will need account for the scope change.

Ember Handlebars mimics that behavior within template loops. If you specify a particular name for the iterated object, `this` will become undefined as the context was given a name.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, {{#each x in model}} is used to maintain the scope, meaning you will be able to access anything on the model from within the loop, so something like this works with {{#each x in model}}

```
{{#each service in model}}
  service.id
  service.name
  this.aVariableOnModel
{{/each}}
```

So essentially, this still remains bounded to the model, and this is very useful and hence its always encouraged to use {{#each x in model}} syntax..

So, in your case, that would mean..if you just do this.

```
<td>{{#link-to 'services.edit' service}}Edit{{/link-to}} - <a href="#" {{action 'deleteService' this}}>Delete</a></td>
```

It will work.

Cheers!